# WordPress permalink to product

Tags: php, wordpress

I am listing out product categories on my website but for some reason the permalink to the product inside the loop is just leading the user to a blog post and not to the product or category etc:

```
<div class="mobile-show">

<?php
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) { ?>
    <?php echo '<ul class="cat_list_mobile">'; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php echo '<li><div class="col-group-2">' . $cat->name . '</div><div class="col-group-2 text-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div></li>
            </a>
          </ul>'; 
}

?>

</div>
```

It is displaying the categories as expected, maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get permalink of the product category then use `get_category_link( $category_id );`

More in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link